# A few JSHint/Syntastic questions for Vim

Tags: vim, vi, jshint, syntastic

I'm using Vim with Syntastic and JSHint, and there are a few bits of glitchy behavior that I'd like to fix.

1. Whenever I modify the last character on a line of text and save (:w), I momentarily see "^M" flash after the text before (sometimes) vanishing. Sometimes it sticks around and I have to manually delete it. What's the deal with this and how do I prevent it?
2. When there is an error in the quickfix view, how do I toggle focus between the quickfix view and the Vim editor window?
3. Vim crashes maybe once per minute, and I haven't the slightest clue as to why, but it's extremely annoying. The error typically reads "Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT Vim: Finished. [1]6099 abort vi gulpfile.js" How do I prevent this?

Here is my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
"Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
"Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Avoid a name conflict with L9
"Plugin 'user/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

" React.js/JSX syntax highlighting
"Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'
"
"JSHint
Plugin 'wookiehangover/jshint.vim'

"Syntastic
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

"Syntastic configuration
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_exec = 'tidy5'
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']
let g:JSHintHighlightErrorLine = 0





syntax on
set t_Co=256
set ai
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set number
"colorscheme monokai
colorscheme skittles_berry
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where your `^M` issue and your crashing issue come from but you don't need such a huge plugin for such a simple task.

Create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` if it doesn't exist and paste the lines below:

- errorformat for jshint

  ```
  setlocal errorformat=%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %m,%-G%.%#
  ```
- tell Vim to use jshint for the `:make` command

  ```
  setlocal makeprg=jshint
  ```
- add an autocommand to run `:make` on the current file upon write, the `| silent wincmd p` at the end switches the focus back to the editing window once the quickfix window is opened

  ```
  autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer> silent make % | silent redraw! | silent wincmd p
  ```

I've never experienced a single crash with that simple setup, or that `^M` issue.

With that in place you should get something like that after `:w`:

[image: poor man's syntastic]

- To move the focus from/to the quickfix window, use `<C-w>p`.
- To jump to the previous/next error without using the quickfix window, use `:cprevious`/`:cnext`.

Reference:

```
:help 'errorformat'
:help 'makeprg'
:help autocmd
:help bufwritepost
:help :silent
:help :redraw
:help :wincmd
:help quickfix
```

Also, check out this great post: [The Power of Vim](https://gist.github.com/ajh17/a8f5f194079818b99199)